# Gravity for Linear Layout

Tags: android, xml, button, user-interface, android-linearlayout

Can anyone help me in giving the gravity for four buttons developed in a vertical linear layout which is again in horizontal linear layout with progress bar. I need the whole buttons and the progress bar in the bottom of my screen. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
> 

 <LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>   
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/pause"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        />
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        />
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/fwd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        />

</LinearLayout>



<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:id="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal"  
  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: could you explain more or any screenshots??

Comment: how to give the XML here

Comment: simply paste your xml here with the question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

add this line to both your vertical as well as horizontal linear layout
I guess this was the answer you were looking for

Comment: what is your problem exactly then?

Comment: i gave a horizontal linear layout with progress bar in it. Then a vertical linear layout with 4 buttons within the horizontal linear layout. The whole layout is displayed on the top of the screen. But I want it to be displayed in the bottom so that I can add an image. Now which command should i use to make it displayed at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: set height of the horizontal layout as wrap_content and then set layout_gravity as bottom

Answer (score 1):

```
 Hi @ srinivas.
    gravity for four buttons developed in a vertical linear layout which is again in horizontal  
    linear layout with progress bar, try out by this xml code.. its must helpful to you...


      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="@android:color/white"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

          <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="First Name"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/firstName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="First Name"
                android:maxLength="20"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000000" >
            </EditText>
          </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Last Name"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/lastName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Last Name"
                android:maxLength="20"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000000" >
            </EditText>
           </LinearLayout>

          <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="UserName"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/un"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="User Name"
                android:maxLength="20"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000000" >
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Password"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/pw"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:maxLength="20"
                android:password="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000000" >
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:maxLength="20"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000000" >
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Phone No."
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/phoneNum"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Phone Number"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="20"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000000" >
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/push_button"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:text="Send Data"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
       </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace with following code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
> 

 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/btnLayout"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal"

>   
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/pause"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        />
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        />
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/fwd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        />

</LinearLayout>



<ProgressBar

    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:id="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal"  

    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  />

</RelativeLayout>
```